# laravel: I cannot complete search form

Tags: php, sql, laravel, forms, search

I am building a search form for `posts` table.

Now I can search description, but when I select a category or date, and search, the result page shows all the posts. Which means search functionality for 'category' and 'date' don't work.

I don't want to build a strict search functionality, so I used `orWhere` query clause.

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('results', 'ResultsController@index')->name('posts.result');
```

`ResultsController.php`

```php
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->get('keyword');
    $category = $request->get('category_id');
    $date = $request->get('date');

    if ($keyword || $category || $date) {
        $posts = Post::Where('keyword', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%')
            ->orWhere('category_id', $category)
            ->orWhere('date', $date)
            ->paginate(10);
        return view('posts.result', compact('posts'));
    } else {
        $posts = Post::latest()
            ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
            ->paginate(10);
        return view('posts.result', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```

**posts table migration**

```php
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('place');
    $table->string('map');
    $table->date('date');
    $table->string('organizer');
    $table->string('organizer_link');
    $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**result.blade.php**

```html
<form action="{{ route('posts.result') }}" class="search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="description" class="search_text" placeholder="Enter the key words">
    <select name="category" id="select" class="Genre">
        <option value="" hidden name="category">Category</option>
        @foreach(App\Category::all() as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="date" class="search_date" id="date" placeholder="Choose date">
    <button type="submit" class="test">
        <i class="fas fa-search "></i>
    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you get any errors? what exactly is not working? also i see you are using orWhere in the category and date without like. but if don’t enter any of them, your query will not return anything. so maybe those should be added to the query conditionally if they exist? you’re assuming that if any of those are present, all are. which we can’t tell from your question.

Comment: I didn't get any errors. My issue is, when I select a category or date, and search, the result page shows all the posts.  Which means search functionality for 'category' and 'date' doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the dd($category, $date); values?

Comment: please add those as conditionals in your query. make sure you only add them to the query if they actually have data passed.

Comment: @Mesuti both values are null.

Comment: Then your form name are not equals with your request parameter which you try to get. I realize first this category is not correct. You can change this line: `<select name="category" id="select" class="Genre">` with this: `<select name="category_id" id="select" class="Genre">` then test again. This can not be null the  '$category` variable.

Comment: you should check if they are empty before adding them to your query. currently you are blindly adding them.  however. the description filter should have filtered the results. i don’t think you are seeing all your posts

Comment: nice catch Mesuti about the category.

Comment: Thanks. Then we want to check the other "date" field but firstly we must be sure the $category is solved? @YoheiUmezu  And my comment about of category is solved can be sign as flag :)

Comment: @Mesuti thanks, I noticed now, but the issue still remains.

Comment: again, please add those to your query only if they exists. if they are empty they should not be part of the query

Comment: Hmm okey. Additionaly to that you can change this line: `<option value="" hidden name="category">Category</option>` with this: `<option value="" hidden>Category</option>`

Comment: i’m on my phone and can’t type a full answer, but i’m pretty sure that if you only query for what you actually send from the form, you should get the right results. rewrite your query to only include what’s not empty.

Comment: I tried php artisan migrate:refresh --seed, and replaced by <option value="" hidden>Category</option> but it didn't be solved...

Comment: @raul What is exact right query to put in ? Could you type when you are free ? Thank you so much.

Comment: sure i’ll get on in about 5m

Comment: @YoheiUmezu i added an answer, please check it out. I have to run out for a few hours. If it does not work, i'll try to run everything locally on my computer and provide you a working variant. But the idea is, you want your query to only execute with the correct filters. Oh, btw, make sure your inputs are correct (keyword, category_id, date), as the others mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to adjust your code to only include the search params that are actually passed. However, could not test it as i have to leave, so please test if this works. The code should work with any of those passed independently, which is why i had to do the `search` array and the `match` key in there.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->get('keyword');
    $category_id = $request->get('category_id');
    $date = $request->get('date');

    if ($keyword || $category_id || $date) {
        $search = [];
        if (!empty($keyword)) {
            $search[] = [
                'column' => 'keyword',
                'value' => "%{$keyword}%",
                'match' => 'LIKE',
            ];
        }

        if (!empty($category_id)) {
            $search[] = [
                'column' => 'category_id',
                'value' => $category_id,
                'match' => '=',
            ];
        }

        if (!empty($date)) {
            $search[] = [
                'column' => 'date',
                'value' => $date,
                'match' => '=',
            ];
        }

        // by here, we have for sure 1 condition
        $posts = Post::where($search[0]['column'], $search[0]['match'], $search[0]['value']);

        if (count($search) > 1) {
            // multiple conditions, using orWhere
            array_shift($search);
            foreach ($search as $condition) {
                $posts->orWhere($condition['column'], $condition['match'], $condition['value']);
            }
        }

        $posts = $posts->paginate(10);
    } else {
        $posts = Post::latest()
            ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
            ->paginate(10);
    }

    return view('posts.result', compact('posts'));
}
```

Your form:

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.result') }}" class="search" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="keyword" class="search_text" placeholder="Enter the key words">
    <select name="category_id" id="select" class="Genre">
        <option value="" hidden>Category</option>
        @foreach(App\Category::all() as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="date" class="search_date" id="date" placeholder="Choose date">
    <button type="submit" class="test">
        <i class="fas fa-search "></i>
    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: But I changed keyword by description. Because I don't have keyword column in my table.

Comment: you’re welcome. yeah you can change whatever you want, code is easy to read and change :). do what you have to do to make it work